# How to get last record from Mysql using Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

```
List<Lahetys> last = session.createQuery("from lahetys order by lahetysNro DESC LIMIT 1").list();
```

and in the log I got:

```
INFO: Hibernate: select  from order by  lahetysNro DESC LIMIT 1
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your       MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order by  lahetysNro DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

What has happend to "from LAHETYS"? What is the best practice to handle that with HQL or/and with SQL?

Another problem:

```
Lahetys last = (Lahetys)session.createSQLQuery("select * from lahetys order by lahetysNro DESC LIMIT 1").uniqueResult();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

and I get a exception:

```
Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Lahetys
```

So I can't cast an object to my Lahetys-object, weird?

Thank you!
Sami

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your HQL query is invalid. LIMIT is not a valid HQL clause. To do that in Hibernate, just do

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from lahetys order by lahetysNro DESC");
query.setMaxResults(1);
Lahetys last = (Lahetys) query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!I got the same exception: ---AsekorjausHelper.getLastLahetysNro()---- 
INFO: Hibernate: select  from order by  lahetysNro DESC limit ?
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order by  lahetysNro DESC limit 1' at line 1
INFO: EXCEPTION OCCURED----->You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order by  lahetysNro DESC limit 1' at line 1

Comment: See @RAS answer. HQL uses entities, mapped fields/properties and associations. Never table and column names.

Comment: @JBNizet why did you use uniqueResult() with setMaxResults(1) when according to documentation uniqueResult method returns single instance

Comment: uniqueResult() expects the query to return a single result, and throws an exception if it's not the case. setMaxResult() tells the database to limit the results to a single row, that I can then get using singleResult().

Answer (score 8):

When you're using HQL, you should specify fully qualified className instead of tableName. The same way you should specify propertyName instead of columnName. Also keep in mind that both are case - sensitive.

Looking at your queries & the exception you're getting, I'm assuming that **lahetys** is your table name & **lahetysNro** is your column name.

You should use for example: If your **Lahetys** class is located at `com` folder:

```
List<Lahetys> last = session.createQuery("from com.Lahetys order by lahetysNro DESC LIMIT 1").list();
```

For your 2nd question:

Here you have used SQL instead of HQL.
When you use SQL with hibernate in such a way, it always returns `List<Object[]>` & not `List<Lahetys[]>`.

Comment: wrong solution: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: limit near line 1.... Use .setMaxResults(1)

Comment: This answer is not correct. See @demon101's comment.

Comment: @demon101, I'm not focusing on `limit` related things over here. That is something OP has used and I'm not talking about it. I'm just explaining the exceptions OP has received and how should he fix them. Usage of `limit` is entirely a different point as well as off-the-context here.

Comment: This solution doenst work, please unmark this as the preferred answer.