# How to get last record from Mysql using Hibernate in NetBeans?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I find the same question [How to get last record from Mysql using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069689/how-to-get-last-record-from-mysql-using-hibernate)     but i dont solved my problem. I want  to get last record from Mysql using Hibernate, this is my code

public class CabinetController implements Controller {

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr,
                                  HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("kabinet");
    String out = "Výpis uživatelů: ";
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
     List result = session.createQuery("from Kabinet ORDER BY id  desc LIMIT 1").list();
        mv.addObject("kor", result);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mv.addObject("message", out);
    return mv;
}
```

resault is full table whith all records, but I want just 1 last record?

Please help me, it is very important for me!!!

Answer (score 3):

Limit does not work in HQL (Hibernate v3+).

You should use MaxResults.

Example with list:

```
List<Kabinet> result = session.createQuery("from Kabinet ORDER BY id DESC")
                          .setMaxResults(1)
                          .list();
```

Example with no list:

```
Kabinet result = (Kabinet) session.createQuery("from Kabinet ORDER BY id DESC")
                              .setMaxResults(1)
                              .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: When i using this query i get this exeption:javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
select * from Kabinet order by id DESC limit 1
```

For MSSQL:

```
select top 1 * from Kabinet order by id DESC
```

For Oracle:

```
select * from Kabinet where rownum<2 order by id DESC
```

Comment: I using  MySQL when i use you code for MySQL I get just header of the table