# How to get the last value of a column using HQL(Hibernate Query Language)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

[image]

As shown in the picture, I need the last value of `bookingID` column using hibernate in MySQL.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Booking listBookingsID() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Booking bookList =  (Booking) session.createQuery("from Booking ORDER BY bookid DESC")
                .setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();


        return bookList;
    }
```

I tried that code which is found in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053438/how-to-get-last-record-from-mysql-using-hibernate-in-netbeans), but it always shows as "9". If the last value is "1" then it should show as 1, but it's 9.

So my question is: "Are there any queries to get the last value of a column in hibernate?"

Comment: You are ordering by the column bookindId in descending order. According to the screenshot 9 is the highest value there. So what exactly isn't working as you expect it? If you want the last entry, don't use bookingId but sort by your primary key!

Comment: @911DidBush even if we use primary key then the value will show as 20 but i need the last value of bookingID. Actually the requirement is like "records will be added to database but 9 is the limit. After 9 records,10th record should start again with bookingID as 1"

Comment: I said you should sort by your primary key. Not that you should select it. Sort by primary key, select bookingId.

Comment: To me, that looks like the first value, not the last (assuming your ids run up, like everybody else's).  To get the first value, order ASC, not DESC, and take the first one.

Comment: In relational databases there is no such concept of last or first record because the resultsets can be ordered in different ways. What you seem to want is to get bookingID of the record where id equals to the maximum of that field (20).

Comment: @Shadow Yeah but in hibernate i don't know whether that type of query still exists or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: @911DidBush If its normal SQL query i shouldn't have had this problem. But i need HQL(Hibernate Query Language)

Comment: @Shadow I am using hibernate,so it needs a query from Hibernate Query Language(HQL). not normal sql query

Comment: I assume Booking is an entity that contains id, bookingId etc, right? So  `Booking booking =  (Booking) session.createQuery("from Booking ORDER BY id DESC")
                .setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult(); return booking.getBookingId();` <- Something like that doesn't work in your case?

Comment: @911DidBush Nope it didn't work in my case. At 9 it will stop and if a new record comes then it takes as 9 always.

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz, it is a `ORDER BY` by `id` instead of `bookingid`.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer then i will get id's as 20,21,22,23....etc. but i need to get the bookingID value relevant to id

Comment: @911DidBush, consider putting your comment as an answer - OP doesn't seem to understand the difference!

Comment: @911DidBush well i did changes to the answer you said and it worked. Please put that comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Database table doesn't have a order itself. So there is no direct way to query for the last entry.

But since your table uses an autoincrement primary key `id` you can get the last inserted entry by sorting the result by this id in descending order and select the first result

```
Booking booking =  (Booking) session.createQuery("from Booking ORDER BY id DESC")
            .setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

This will get you the Booking with the highest `id`, now all you have to do is select the `bookingId` of that entry:

```
  return booking.getBookingId();
```

Comment: Yep Thanks for solving my issue which was there for a day. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Maximum ID of your table like:

```
HibernateEntityManager he;

long lastID = ((Number) he.createNativeQuery("select max(id) from table;").getSingleResult()).longValue();
```

then you can get the bookingID from it with searching for the row with **lastID**

if you use JPA, it would be like this:

```
long bookingID;
bookingID = bookRepository.findOne(lastID).getBookingID;
```

Comment: Is there a query through "session" and "session factory" rather that "HibernateEntityManager"??

Comment: I don't know. I am a rookie myself. **HibernateEntityManager** is the only way i know so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Booking bookList =  (Booking) session.createQuery("from Booking ORDER BY bookid DESC")
    .setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```